# How can one make Salesforce Bulk API calls via simple_salesforce?

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I'm using the module `simple-salesforce`, and I'm not seeing anything in the docs about making bulk API calls.  Anybody know how to do this?

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[The code](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/bulk.py) does have some comments. There's also [this readthedocs page](http://simple-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple_salesforce.bulk.html) but, even that looks like it could use some help.

Good stuff first, explanation below.

Code example (written assuming you're running the whole block of code at once):

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(<credentials>)

# query
accounts = sf.bulk.Account.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 5')
# returns a list of dictionaries similar to: [{'Name': 'Something totally new!!!', 'attributes': {'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account/object_id_1', 'type': 'Account'}, 'Id': 'object_id_1'}]

# assuming you've pulled data, modify it to use in the next statement
accounts[0]['Name'] = accounts[0]['Name'] + ' - Edited'
# update
result = sf.bulk.Account.update(accounts)
# result would look like [{'errors': [], 'success': True, 'created': False, 'id': 'object_id_1'}]

# insert
new_accounts = [{'Name': 'New Bulk Account - 1', 'BillingState': 'GA'}]
new_accounts = sf.bulk.Account.insert(new_accounts)
# new_accounts would look like [{'errors': [], 'success': True, 'created': True, 'id': 'object_id_2'}]

# upsert
accounts[0]['Name'] = accounts[0]['Name'].replace(' - Edited')
accounts.append({'Name': 'Bulk Test Account'})
# 'Id' is the column to "join" on. this uses the object's id column
upserted_accounts = sf.bulk.Account.upsert(accounts, 'Id')
# upserted_accounts would look like [{'errors': [], 'success': True, 'created': False, 'id': 'object_id_1'}, {'errors': [], 'success': True, 'created': True, 'id': 'object_id_3'}]

# how i assume hard_delete would work (i never managed to run hard_delete due to insufficient permissions in my org)
# get last element from the response.
# *NOTE* This ASSUMES the last element in the results of the upsert is the new Account.
#  This is a naive assumption
new_accounts.append(upserted_accounts[-1])
sf.bulk.Account.hard_delete(new_accounts)
```

Using simple_salesforce, you can access the bulk api by doing

```
<your Salesforce object>.bulk.<Name of the Object>.<operation to perform>(<appropriate parameter, based on your operation>)
```

- `<your Salesforce object>` is the object you get back from constructing `simple_salesforce.Salesforce(<credentials>)`

  - `<credentials>` is your `username`, `password`, `security_token`, and `sandbox`(bool, if you're connecting to a sandbox) or `session_id`. (these are the 2 ways that i know of)
- `<Name of the Object>` is just `Account` or `Opportunity` or whatever object you're trying to manipulate
- `<operation to perform>` is one of the below:

  - query
  - insert
  - update
  - upsert
  - hard_delete (my account did not have appropriate permissions to test this operation. any mention is pure speculation)
- `<appropriate parameter>` is dependent on which operation you wish to perform

  - query - a string that contains a SOQL
  - insert - a list of dictionaries. remember to have a key for all fields required by your org when creating a new record
  - update - a list of dictionaries. you'll obviously need a valid Object Id per dictionary
  - upsert - a list of dictionaries and a string representing the "external id" column. The "external id" can be the Salesforce Object `'Id'` or any other column; choose wisely. If any dictionary does not have a key that is the same as the "external id", a new record will be created.
- What's returned: depends on the operation.

  - query returns a list of dictionaries with your results. In addition to the columns your query, each dictionary has an `'attributes'` key. This contains a `'url'` key, which looks like it can be used for api requests for the specific object, key and `'type'` key, which is the type of the Object returned
  - insert/update/upsert returns a list of dictionaries. each dictionary is like `{'errors': [], 'success': True, 'created': False, 'id': 'id of object would be here'}`

Thanks to [@ATMA's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241330/simple-salesforce-making-bulk-sql-calls-within-a-date-range) for showing how was using `query`. With that question and the source code, was able to figure out `insert`, `update`, and `upsert`.

Comment: This should be the best answer

Comment: Hi @Terminus, can you show some example of uploading attachments and relating it to an ID using simple_salesforce?

Comment: @lollerskates haven't ever had to try that. (Haven't even dealt with salesforce in a long time) I think some people watch the simple-salesforce tag; you might have some luck opening a good question using it. Good luck!